# Windows Phone 7 push notification when the app is not running

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am trying to implement push notifications in windows phone 7.5

I bind the channelUri in App.xaml when the application starts up. 
I can then switch my app to background and receive toast notifications based on the Uri.

But this requires me to first go the app and then make it to background.

Can I receive the toast without the app running? That is when the channelUri is not bound.

Is this a default behaviour in Windows phone 7 or whether I am missing a point here?

If this is the behaviour, how can I send some form of notification/ information to the phone when the app is not running?

I did see this [Windows Phone 7.5 - Push Notifications when app is tombstoned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10340474/windows-phone-7-5-push-notifications-when-app-is-tombstoned).

Update:

1. I know the Channel is active up to 30 days, is it the same when I use only emulator?
2. App should be associated with a channel so as to receive notification and even when app is not running, if the notification channel is active, then the application will receive the  toast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing the point. In order to receive toast notifications you don't have to have the app running in the background. Toasts (and Tile notifications) are meant for when the app is not running at all. So, start the app to get a push-uri and then send that to the service. In theory you won't need one again after 30 days. When it comes to the emulator it will be available as long as the emulator is running. Once you shutdown/close the emulator, the push-uri is gone and you would need to re-request one. (Generally speaking, nothing is saved on the emulator and so closing and opening the emulator is like getting a new device everytime.)

Hopefully this helps

Comment: Is that 30 day a sure count, so that the channel is always reliable within 30 days or will it expire before that?

Comment: No it is not a sure count. So, from a client-service programming point of view you should detect this case. In other terms, if you cannot retrieve the uri from your device, the app must recognize that and request another one. That URI should then be sent to the service with an identifier so that on the server side there is continuity in delivering the service to your app. An example of an identifier could be your device ID or, the username of the user on that service. Also, on the service side you can detect expiry of channel URIs in the header of responses (X-SubscriptionStatus) to POSTs.